# identify the type/ namespace of any c#/ asp.net keyword

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms

I want to call a method from `example.cs` class file, to display alert message box to the client. This method contains a `ClientScript.Register...` method (as shown below). But Visual Studio shows a red underline under `ClientScript` method. I want to call (reuse) this method from other `aspx` pages to generate appropriate messages.
code snippet:

```
public AlertBox(string message)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("')};");
        sb.Append("</script>");


       ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());

    }
```

So the red underline keeps me to generate this alert box. so as per my knowledge 
I would like reference the type `(namespace)` of `ClientScript` keyword. Please suggest me some ways to achieve this thing.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717814/c-net-how-do-i-find-the-containing-namespace-from-a-class-name

Comment: i also would like to take guidance in solving this issue.nThan lu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ScriptManager in class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956707/how-to-use-scriptmanager-in-class-file)